# In UINavigationController, button doesn't work with pushViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I want to make a simple navigation control application in which I have two view controllers(`ViewController` and `ViewController2`). I have a button in `ViewController` and when I press the button, I want it to go to the other view. The problem is that button doesn't work. I also tried the `UIViewController`, but didn't work in that way neither.

The AppDelegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    ViewController *vc1 = [[ViewController alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc1];

    self.window.rootViewController = nav;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window addSubview:nav.view];
    return YES;
}
```

The ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender {

    ViewController *vc2 = [[ViewController alloc]init];

    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it doesn't work? Does nothing happen at all, or the application crashes when you press the button?

Comment: nothing happens at all when I press the button

Comment: have you set the "sent event" in the *.xib file?

Comment: Yes, a touch Up Inside for button

Answer (score 0):

if you use storyboard import in your ViewController1 the ViewController2 and give a storyboard ID to it "view2":

```
  ViewController2 *vc2 = (ViewController2 *)[self.storyboard instatiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

Comment: I use .xib files, could you tell me how to do this with .xib?

Comment: i'm not sure but try:   ViewController2 *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nameOfYourController"];